# Fetch, scrape and process external website in a servlet, should I do it in doGet or doPost?

Tags: java, selenium, servlets

I have some issues with architecture of my service. My task is the following:

1. First of all I need to create a Servlet and send some information when I invoke **HTTP GET** request. Something like this:

http://localhost:8080/?startDate=05/15/2016&endDate=05/22/2016&origin=HKG&destination=LHR

Okay, I get this info with the following code in my servlet's method doGet():

```
String startDate = req.getParameter("startDate").toString();
String endDate = req.getParameter("endDate").toString();
String origin = req.getParameter("origin").toString();
String destination = req.getParameter("destination").toString();
```

2.Then, using this info I need to complete form on the real website(not mine) and this website doesn't have any relation with my Servlet. I did it via Selenium libraries such as HTMLUnit. All these things are performed by some methods in other class, but these methods invoked in **doGet()** of servlet. Form on those website was complete and i was transferred on new webpage with the results

3.Then, i need to parse these result in the way i have to. No matter what this way is. Parsed result should appear on the webpage linked with my Servlet

The question is how should position all these steps in my servlet? what I should pass into **doGet()** method? what I should pass into **doPost()**? How to invoke **doPost()** in this way? Because now i do it all in doGet() and I think this not the best way since **HTTP GET** should be idempotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `doPost` method since client pass you data in uri or alias in `get request`. 
You just need to fetch data from external website and constract you response:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response){

        // your request parsing

        // Your Magic with Selenium

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String data = //your data fetched from website by `Selenium` library 
        out.println(//**html with embedded  data **//)
}
```

---

One note:
It looks very suspicious. I don't think it will work fine. As I know Selenium need some time for navigation, etc. so you are prone to catch `timeout` error codes

Comment: I do it as you described but as I read everywhere, I shouldn't use doGet() for doing something like a parsing other webpage since doGet() is idempotent. And may be I need redesign my service and use doPost someway, if I do, how?

Comment: Yes if you care about forbiding client browser to cache responses from your side. Your `doGet` method is `idempotent` since you just return current state of things like, lets, say `getTime` do, but if you make `doPost` on the external website then obviously better use `doPost` also

Comment: But these `doPost` calls are implicit since `HTMLUnit` provide it. I just don't understand how to call `doPost` of my Servlet

Comment: Then just rename method above to `doPost` provide client with html form eg(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) or just test it with `curl` eg: `curl -d "startDate=05/15/2016&endDate=05/22/2016&origin=HKG&destination=LHR" --dump-header headers http://localhost:8080/`. Keep parsing parameters as it is. On the bottom of `doPost` method you can call `doGet()` where you will just do nothing except constructing response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `RequestDispatcher`

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

> Defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends
>   them to any resource (such as a servlet, **HTML** file, or JSP file) on
>   the server. The servlet container creates the RequestDispatcher
>   object, which is used as a wrapper around a server resource located at
>   a particular path or given by a particular name.

Look at the method:

`void forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)`

Try to send parameters using ServletRequest object and get a response.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstand question. OP wants to fetch data from external website by Selenium(http://www.seleniumhq.org/) not redirect client to external website.